# timezone and daylight savings

Tags: android, timezone

hi I need to get the timezone of a person to display a certain info depending on this timezone:
what I'm gonna use is:

```
  TimeZone tz = cal.getTimeZone();
```

but does this timezone change when there's daylight savings? and if I need to get the timezone of a certain location will the daylight savings ruine my result?

Answer (score 8):

You can use this to figure out if you're in DST:

```
boolean isDST = tz.inDaylightTime(time);
```

And you can use this to figure out how much time to add in milliseconds (some places use DST times different than one hour):

```
int dstMillisec = tz.getDSTSavings();
```

Hope this helps :)